# How for...of Loop Statement Works in Javascript?(ECMAScript 6)

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6

I have a snippet which I'm experimenting the `for...of` statement on it:

```
let arr = [3, 5, 7];
arr.foo = "hello";

for (let i in arr) {
   console.log(i); // logs "0", "1", "2", "foo"
}

for (let i of arr) {
   console.log(i); // logs "3", "5", "7"
}
```

My Question is that `for...of` should run on iterable values, right? so why the second `for` doesn't print `"hello"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are iterables over their **elements**. That's how it's defined. That is how [`Array[Symbol.iterator]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator) is implemented.

See http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-iteration.html.

Comment: so you mean foo is a property, not an element. but aren't array indexes, properties themselves?

Comment: 0 and `foo` are both properties, while `3` is an element but `hello` is not. Elements are the values that occur as values of integer-valued properties.