# Why for..of does not log the foo value?

Tags: javascript

I am looking at a sample from mozilla documents about JS and here is this snippet that shows that For..of prints 3, 5, 7, but why not "hello"?

```
let arr = [3, 5, 7];
arr.foo = "hello";

for (let i in arr) {
   console.log(i); // logs "0", "1", "2", "foo"
}

for (let i of arr) {
   console.log(i); // logs "3", "5", "7" ?????
}
```

Comment: You've copied the examples from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Difference_between_for...of_and_for...in), however you didn't read what it says, _While `for...in` iterates over property names, `for...of` iterates over property values:_. `hello` is the **value** of the key `foo`.

Comment: And there is a a property called "foo" with a value "hello". Why doesn't it show it?

Comment: @Tushar Did you try the code? "Hello" is indeed not printed.

Comment: Yes, and my question is Why? Isn't foo the fourth element of arr?

Comment: BTW, MDN is not always correct. It's better to try the sample code then see the ouput.

Comment: @v.g.: No. `arr[3]` is undefined. `arr.foo` is just an arbitrary property of the array, like `arr.length` is, it's not an array element. Only integer-indexed properties are.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are iterables over their elements. That's how it's defined. That is how [Array[Symbol.iterator]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator) is implemented.

See [this](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-iteration.html).

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091263/how-for-of-loop-statement-works-in-javascriptecmascript-6).

EDIT:
foo is property. 3, for example, is an element but "hello" isn't. Elements are the values that occur as values of integer-valued properties.